# Execute the same code in action performed of a button, when click enter from a textfield

Tags: java, swing

I have a class extending JDialog. In that i place a JTextField and a JButton (jButton1).
There is some code inside jButton1ActionPerformed.

I want to execute the same code when I enter some values in the JTextField and click enter button.

Answer (score 1):

Have your class implement ActionListener and put your code inside the `actionPerformed` method. You can then set the instance to be the actionListener on both the button and text field.

```
public MyDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
{
  JTextField myTextField;
  JButton myButton;

  public MyDialog()
  {
    //set up and add components here

    myButton.addActionListener(this);
    myTextField.addActionListner(this);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
  {
    //code here that does stuff when button pressed, or enter pressed on text field
  }
}
```

Comment: +1,or you can also create an Action which can be added to both listeners. The advantage of using an Action is that you can potentially disable/enable the Action and Actions can be used with Key Bindings if ever required.

Answer (score 0):

```
jButton1.doClick();
```

you can call it